# Rails Association Validations: The field, or the _id field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

One of the messier practices I have in Rails development is juggling validations of associated  fields between validating the actual object (eg: validates_presence_of :related_object) and validating on the id column for that association (eg: validates_presence_of :related_object_id).

I figure I should probably start being a little more consistent with this, and before I commit to anything, I'm wondering if there's any advantage of either method over the other? I can't think of anything, but then I've been known to overlook stuff before. So, does it make any difference? Is there a convention re: what most developers do that I should abide by?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question comes up every so often.

In most cases you will want to validate the presence of **the actual associated object**, not just verify that an id (which could well be invalid) has been set.

Validating `association_id` will also prevent you from creating the object with a new association record and saving both together.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to check the presence of `:object_id`. If you check the presence of `:object` then this object will be fetched from your DB and then will be checked  via simple `blank?`. I guess you won't be happy with additional DB hit.